# Redirecting non-www to www in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what i have written in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.spreadcreativity\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/spreadcreativity\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

in my browser it is displaying as https://spreadcreativity.org

But i want to show it as https://www.spreadcreativity.org

Please Help me to rectify this .

Thanks.

Comment: Redirecting non-www to www domain is a task solved long ago. Plz, look at the question I gave and comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: @user4035 it did not help me so i posted as new question did u get it so please remove that down voting..

Comment: "so please remove that down voting" - I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this after clearing cache of your web browser :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.spreadcreativity.org/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```